# Generate A298757

Tags: primes, fastest-code

### Miller-Rabin test

Given a base \$b\$ and an odd number \$n\$:

Write \$n\$ as \$2^{s}\times d + 1\$ where \$d\$ is odd

\$n\$ is a *strong probable prime* if either:

- \$b^d\equiv 1 \pmod n\$
- \$b^{d\cdot2^r}\equiv -1 \pmod n\$

for any non-negative \$r\$ strictly less than \$s\$.

A  *strong probable prime* which is composite is a *pseudoprime*.

See [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_pseudoprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_pseudoprime) for more information.

### Challenge

Make a script that generates very good bases (bases, \$b\$, for which the first *pseudoprime* is larger than with any smaller base).

### Additional rules

1. Your script should be as fast as possible.
2. Your script should not use a lookup table (for the output, lookup table for primes is fine).
3. You may use external libraries as long as that library is written in the same language.
4. Speed will be measured in terms of how many terms it can generate in 1 min.

### Python implementation of the Miller-Rabin test

```python
def miller(n, b):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return n == 2
    d = n - 1
    s = 0
    while d % 2 == 0:
        d >>= 1
        s += 1
    if pow(b, d, n) == 1:
        return True
    elif any(pow(b, d * 2 ** r, n) == n - 1 for r in range(s)):
        return True
    return False
```

An entry is valid if it will never stop producing better bases and it won't produce a base worse than it has generated before.

Example of a valid python entry:

```python
from sympy import isprime
base = 2
record = 2
while True:
    number = 9
    while True:
        while isprime(number):
            number += 2
        if miller(number, base):
            if number > record:
                record = number
                print(base)
            break
        number += 2
    base += 1
```

Little over 20 sec to generate:

```
2
1320
4712
5628
7252
7852
14787
17340
61380
78750
```

My code generates the above in ca. 20 sec on my laptop, and generates one more term in 72 sec. so the score is 10 terms.

Arnauld pointed out that the challenge is just to generate [A298757](https://oeis.org/A298757).

Sympy's isprime is not the problem as it runs in less than .5 sec for 700 digit numbers.

Edit:
I didn't mean to give advantage to specific languages like C, so I will convert them to python.

Comment: _not accepting answers_ is a consequence of a question being closed, not a reason explaining why it was closed. Once a question is clarified and re-opened, users are allowed to answer it again.

Comment: The appropriate action when your question is closed is not to delete it and repost it. You should have edited your previous post and waited for it to be reopened. After doing some tests I came to the same conclusion that the prime test was not the most significant factor for small inputs, though I'd still be worried it would dominate for larger values. Regardless, please spend some time reading the help centre so you are more aware of what the purpose of this site is. Also consider using our [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/31625).

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Thank you for explaining, English is not my native language and I may have misinterpreted the reason. Btw, sympy uses a baillie PSW test so even for 700 digit numbers it takes less than 0.2 sec, so it won't dominate for values that my implementation above will ever deal with.

Comment: *"Edit: I didn't mean to give advantage to specific languages like C, so I will convert them to python."*, no, that's terrible. C and C++ should be allowed to use processor-specific features. If someone writes a solution in some esoteric language, I'm sure as *hell* that you won't be able to convert it into Python, and most likely they won't be able to either.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear per @S.S.Anne's comment

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), \$n = 15\$

```rust
use std::collections::VecDeque;

fn miller(n: u64, mut b: u64) -> bool {
    let s = (n - 1).trailing_zeros();
    let mut t = n - 1 >> s;
    b %= n;
    let mut a = b;
    while t != 1 {
        b = b * b % n;
        t >>= 1;
        if t & 1 != 0 {
            a = a * b % n;
        }
    }
    if a == 1 || a == n - 1 {
        return true;
    }
    for _ in 1..s {
        a = a * a % n;
        if a == n - 1 {
            return true;
        }
        if a == 1 {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

fn main() {
    let mut record = 2;
    let mut factor = VecDeque::new();

    for base in 2.. {
        factor.clear();
        let mut q = 3;
        let mut qq = q * q;
        for n in (9..).step_by(2) {
            let mut p = factor.pop_front().unwrap_or(0);

            if n == qq {
                if p == 0 {
                    p = q;
                }
                q += 2;
                qq = q * q;
            } else if p == 0 {
                continue;
            }

            if miller(n as u64, base) {
                if n > record {
                    println!("{}", base);
                    record = n;
                }
                break;
            }

            let mut m = p - 1;
            while *factor.get(m).unwrap_or(&0) != 0 {
                m += p;
            }
            if factor.len() < m + 1 {
                factor.resize(m + 1, 0);
            }
            factor[m] = p;
        }
    }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVTdbtowFL7nKU4rrXK6ElE6TVoY3GzPsJtpQk7qMGuOHWxnaG159WXnYEwSSKv5AqHj7@f8ObZxvm0bJ8D5xywrjFKi8NJol2XfRPFVbBuxmExKDZXEK8t0Bs3HD3dQNR7yw/8EpivIjVHwPAE8SnhwsASmYQr3Seotl0rqzfpJWONYsjihSMMj8gCE1QpcuMvhHQaHOI64PIR2P6USSLxaIit4BhYi4JbYkUzHozACu4AsMXaDVOTPenw65MIvNfaT7hfpiCLrl5fwL6TfCVnhG6vBW2pdRyyNhTVIDfdp6nrw6MmHntHnXH3UoXMZpjhKK7lyYry4IWIfBs@lZklvuDQOKwpjHzHz@XBMJS881rmEuDxZpsWOhn7qQc5x27AN8zTt5ReIaaEEt3FH@sJb1HwYCVN8i93bdndkosmBfUrTJHVe1Ov8D5snZ@2IGjVKHO1rU69La7RnSdroneX12lg2i@n3Gqypweg@lDxe1nQ5G7mjQ3a9bC/HF88W3p/6O4iP1HxQAKGotW/4F1ia1P2tCdbn1cXHDtyF505DS8aL1bCK6/BKwVZqr/QVu37eXx@lFqPI01bp/@lPbgX/9WYlccIVStb0jobo8CG5Pc5@Izyr@mO/mSVj3wg6FY2mPvc@a8xRVwl6Pp@Jc/Eie5tvhZNPgh1QdzBL3hIPlO/VDxhkEV/yvm3/FqXiG9dOv7Sm9lMlfgu1fPgH)

Comment: It seems like Rust is good at these fastest-code challenges.

Comment: Either Rust or Anders Kaseorg...or both :)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), \$n=15\$

This is essentially just a port of the example implementation, with an optimized modular exponentiation and a cache for odd composite numbers.

Further optimized by merging `powMod()` and `miller()`, as [Anders Kaseorg first did](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200635/58563).

```javascript
function miller(n, b) {
  let s = 31 - Math.clz32(n - 1 & 1 - n);
  let t = n - 1 >> s;
  let k = b %= n;

  while(t != 1) {
    b = (b * b) % n;

    if((t >>= 1) & 1) {
      k = (k * b) % n;
    }
  }
  if(k == 1 || k == n - 1) {
    return true;
  }
  while(k != 1 && --s) {
    if((k = (k * k) % n) == n - 1) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function isPrime(n) {
  let m = n ** 0.5;

  for(let d = 3; d <= m; d += 2) {
    if(!(n % d)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function nthOddComposite(n) {
  if(n < oddComposite.length) {
    return oddComposite[n];
  }

  let k;

  for(k = oddComposite[oddComposite.length - 1]; isPrime(k += 2);) {}
  oddComposite.push(k);

  return k;
}

let oddComposite = [ 9 ];
let ts = +new Date();

for(let i = 0, record = base = 2;; base++) {
  for(let j = 0;; j++) {
    number = nthOddComposite(j);

    if(miller(number, base)) {
      if(number > record) {
        record = number;
        console.log(
          ++i + '\tbase = ' + base + '\ttime = ' + ((new Date() - ts) / 1000).toFixed(2)
        );
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVNNc5swEL3zK14OdoSxXeNMDh0Cl3Z667T3NAc@5CADkgdE02nj3@6uxGfiHBjBvre7b9@KY/w7btJanPRGqoxfLodWplooiUqUJa@ZXCNx8c8BSq7RIMSdjw2@xzrfpuXfuz2T9OljCROWbtAzNTE7JIrQDNGCogkWBAUOhV5yUXKmcRPC75qA4BAswcq0XfQ8QBwY8aLIEpcTG7YkK2Z8Ezw73UNphFMSXl9h36ymIbvmuq0ldN3yoM/oJBVWEpZLbDbNwDYaxm6F7eZelbwqOonpgUNcNoScHWf0WjQ/a1FxJienK@vfaoXd9t56cFA1M0BmVhDQ8RCiMqcXYj@TeEMLWSBzrwT1fT9Q1EmdC5I6/5FlX1R1Uo3QozAqL/EANYO2JZfPOn/n6JzxKJ86c4c7MI5jzHzD/KCw8fYpGB0qunED6mcGeJNwapucFa4t3@so7Fim65xJbR/xGSTL3lRzqT3JX/A1plFN/uC1IGS3pmKpqo3vSdyY5D3pIRv8@8BGPK@bfsg6mqwgwHEAANlWCa/NSt8Ze3SnCz78cZa7tqVnWzTed1WiXtCEYZLYcYIRSJVsVEluqmc2BgHPE/Bw@0v3I93Sl321QU1W90HGJmdoF5r@hk/wd7udu9Xqm/jDM7Z3x8Lu0Pjcn0nN42J@6c6Xy38) (this TIO link has \$n\le15\$ as a hard-coded limit)

#### Output

```
1       base = 2        time = 0.00
2       base = 1320     time = 0.02
3       base = 4712     time = 0.03
4       base = 5628     time = 0.04
5       base = 7252     time = 0.04
6       base = 7852     time = 0.05
7       base = 14787    time = 0.07
8       base = 17340    time = 0.07
9       base = 61380    time = 0.18
10      base = 78750    time = 0.22
11      base = 254923   time = 0.62
12      base = 486605   time = 1.14
13      base = 1804842  time = 4.05
14      base = 4095086  time = 9.13
15      base = 12772344 time = 28.41
--------------------------------------> time limit
16      base = 42162995 time = 94.23
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), \$n=14\$

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>

template <typename I>
bool isPrime(I n)
{
    if (n < 2) {
        return false;
    }
    if (n == 2 || n == 3) {
        return true;
    }
    if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    I srt = std::sqrt(n);
    int inc = 4;
    for (I i = static_cast<I>(5); i <= srt; i += inc)
    {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        inc = 6 - inc;
    }
    return true;
}

template <typename I>
I pow(I base, I exp, I mod)
{
    I result = 1;
    for (;;)
    {
        if (exp & 1) {
            result = (result * base) % mod;
        }
        exp >>= 1;
        if (!exp) {
            break;
        }
        base = (base * base) % mod;
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename I>
bool miller(I n, I b)
{
    if (n % 2 == 0) return n == 2;
    I d = n - 1;
    I s = 0;
    while (d % 2 == 0)
    {
        d >>= 1;
        s += 1;
    }
    if (pow<I>(b, d, n) == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < s; ++r) {
            if (pow<I>(b, d * (1 << r), n) == n - 1) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

template <typename I>
void genBase()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    I base = 2;
    I record = 2;
    int count = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        I number = 9;
        while (true)
        {
            while (isPrime(number))
            {
                number += 2;
            }
            if (miller(number, base))
            {
                if (number > record)
                {
                    record = number;
                    auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
                    auto diff = now - start;
                    std::cout << std::setw(3) << ++count << ". " << std::setw(10) << base << 
                        " @ " << std::setprecision(4) << std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(diff).count()/1000 << " s\n";
                }
                break;
            }
            number += 2;
        }
        base++;
    }
}

int main(){
    genBase<unsigned long long>();
    return 0;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVXtbtMwFP3fp7gUDcWkHc02kGjSCPGvv@ABkKZ8uJ21xA62w5hYX53u2k6a5mOwSFuSm/t5zrluVlXLrEj4/nh8y3hW1DmFiAmlJU3KeNbZsjLRdz3DnRRcnFuYKBPOqng207SsikSjTT9WlCclhW08S4UogKnvkpXU2wInsz8zwIvtwOMQwRUBZzCXpLqWHHZJoWhorYcz580GruDpCezT9USclvVE2AVGYcDKhV7AtX17TdktKKlhA0rn67X6KbXHifvOuMa/DL/dOMNOSMDxmPVONMtus0TpaBt7H0mI5mhjcpknf2MiiY3qWmhbZaPmphvsmnTtmFY@wdI8nU/QA@bwEkdbqMQDdp8mii5wavq7MrdS5C1bW8yk6sKAEZwNHIZTc2A4vINgPESTwWue3tuCBKfGSlNjmURxfCrZ5n@D9mHyFKV7P5XDlDA17X2iYg8n19g/kLJqLllRUGnEbFBK@4pu1UbanE63YQNjjr1w5CloDQoNK/fycMcKCl7e5RiAmw/RUEZNwVDySKYRXrqAfIELZ1IFw1QvbAxFgQ08LdFG79J2ircIVAi@L4ccDGoj2l4AUQSStG3YyYdhk@2MiTyM6Wr24UW2fgmWw57yr0i619KU1FqYHe022x1quOGaJvnjbVaI7H695rgSpGWpUdGJRkkzIfPOYvDJRM31iE0z0hB8VE5dptQA@rkbdxTQDzpzaY9Tl4WQns8Y3KaYf@p2DG5LXyNtF7Fw2/K/9Fb3rkTcAENGTuMwx2MDo4sPJ50sYcjGq@maTJCz3c4UwjxLR/@0sysham2U6w5@qh88/LnBd993JOPj/BLmfZdgZX2sVPA@md1cc/jSD60QBqaY4N4NOdnbKfNa4s@J4FEu6rTA49l@NTyx2DNDkUvbk0c@BKvVyrYG6gefj8c7jCyDU3PsNCmd/uHq@@0Bgnto9qBMGPeII7xZvqjmiu05zaEQfG//xS1bzS7j1hyOx7/Zrkj26rj8dv0M)

Basically a port of the OP's Python solution.

#### Output:

```cpp
 1.          2 @ 0.001043 s  
 2.       1320 @ 0.0234 s  
 3.       4712 @ 0.06999 s  
 4.       5628 @ 0.08394 s  
 5.       7252 @ 0.1051 s  
 6.       7852 @ 0.117 s  
 7.      14787 @ 0.2111 s   
 8.      17340 @ 0.244 s   
 9.      61380 @ 0.8129 s    
10.      78750 @ 1.022 s   
11.     254923 @ 3.133 s   
12.     486605 @ 5.843 s   
13.    1804842 @ 21.69 s   
14.    4095086 @ 48.38 s
```